# R data.table syntax to replace multiple values in a column

Tags: r, data.table

This is probably very simple to do but I'm having a hard time finding a way to do this. I have a data.table `dt` with many columns. If one of the columns is `sex` containing values `Male`, `Female` and `""`, I want to remap those values to `Male`=`M`, `Female`=`F` and `""`=NA. How can I do this without using `ifelse`.

Comment: I'm curious why this question received several upvotes despite having no sample data and demonstrating no effort or research. Also, while `ifelse` has issues, why exactly are you trying to avoid it? Are you also avoiding the related functions `data.table::fifelse` (and `dplyr::if_else`, off-tag though)? Remapping values can be done as well using `switch` (needing to be vectorized) or `dplyr::recode`.

Answer (score 7):

There are many solutions available. Here, I'll focus on `base`-R or `data.table` solutions.

#### Data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(sex = c("Male", "Female", ""))
```

##### Option 1:

You could use `fcase` (which basically is a nested `ifelse`):

```
dt[, sex := fcase(sex == "Male", "M", sex == "Female", "F")]

    sex
1:    M
2:    F
3: <NA>
```

Be aware that by default everything that isn't matched by `fcase` is set to `NA`. You can always provide more 'cases' if needed (as in `sex == "", NA, ...`).

##### Option 2:

You could set it as a factor and relabel the levels:

```
dt[, sex := factor(sex, levels = c("Male", "Female"), labels = c("M", "F"))]

    sex
1:    M
2:    F
3: <NA>
```

##### Option 3: (provided by @thelatemail)

```
dt[.(old = c("Male", "Female", ""), new = c("M", "F", NA)), on = .(sex = old), sex := new]

    sex
1:    M
2:    F
3: <NA>
```

##### Option 4: (provided by @jay.sf)

Using `substring`.

```
dt[, sex := substring(replace(sex, sex == "", NA), 1, 1)]

    sex
1:    M
2:    F
3: <NA>
```

##### Option 5:

A `data.table` version of `match` (inspired by @jblood94).

```
dt[, sex := c("M", "F", NA)[chmatch(sex, c("Male", "Female", ""))]]

    sex
1:    M
2:    F
3: <NA>
```

##### Option 6: (provided by @s_baldur)

Creation of a lookup-table.

```
LUT <- data.table(sex = c("Male", "Female", ""), to=c("M", "F", NA), key = "sex")
dt[, sex := LUT[.SD, to]]

    sex
1:    M
2:    F
3: <NA>
```

---

*Let me know if you have another solution that I could add here!*

#### Microbenchmarking:

I used `sample` on the data because ordered values were giving **option 1** and **option 2** an edge over the others. *

```
library(microbenchmark)

#data
dt.bm <- data.table(sex = sample(rep(c("Male", "Female", ""), 100000)))

#benchmarking
microbenchmark(
        option_1 = copy(dt.bm)[, sex := fcase(sex == "Male", "M", sex == "Female", "F")],
        option_2 = copy(dt.bm)[, sex := factor(sex, levels = c("Male", "Female"), labels = c("M", "F"))],
        option_3 = copy(dt.bm)[.(old=c("Male","Female",""), new=c("M","F",NA)), on=.(sex=old), sex := new],
        option_4 = copy(dt.bm)[, sex := substring(replace(sex, sex == "", NA), 1, 1)],
        option_5 = copy(dt.bm)[, sex := c("M", "F", NA)[chmatch(sex, c("Male", "Female", ""))]],
        option_6 = {LUT <- data.table(sex = c("Male", "Female", ""), to=c("M", "F", NA), key = "sex"); copy(dt.bm)[, sex := LUT[.SD, to]]},
        times = 10L
        )
```

##### Results:

**Option 5** is the best performing one when it comes to speed. **

```
#results
Unit: milliseconds
     expr    min     lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
 option_1 6.7219 6.7816  7.76613  6.85335  9.7207 10.3584    10
 option_2 6.1356 6.1981  7.18201  6.29060  9.2294  9.4921    10
 option_3 8.6486 8.6935 10.61704 10.29420 12.5258 13.0865    10
 option_4 8.1740 8.2124  9.10800  8.31170  9.1615 12.3198    10
 option_5 3.3497 3.3843  3.84333  3.44340  3.4822  7.5465    10
 option_6 6.0769 6.2583  6.99274  6.51460  6.6087  9.6276    10
```

**In an ordered situation **option 2** would clock in at a mean around 3.9 milliseconds (data not shown).*

***This only considers `base` and `data.table` solutions. Using `collapse::join` as suggested by @s_baldurs answer results in a mean time of about 3.1 milliseconds and `fastmatch::fmatch` (@jblood94) would be the fastest approach so far with 3.0 milliseconds (data not shown).*

Comment: I think this is probably 'the way' to go about it (+1) as it will be more flexible, but you could also do it as a join in this instance - `dt[.(old=c("Male","Female",""), new=c("M","F",NA)), on=.(sex=old), sex := new]`

Comment: The `factor` solution should be simpler doing `dt[, sex := factor(sex, levels = c("Male", "Female"), labels = c("M", "F"))]`. Values not included in `levels=` argument become `NA`.

Comment: Another solution could be `dt[, sex := substr(replace(sex, sex == "", NA), 1, 1)]`.

Comment: This will generally be more performant: `dt[, sex := c("M", "F", NA)[match(sex, c("Male", "Female", ""))]]` (and even more so with `fastmatch::fmatch`).

Comment: @s_baldur fixed it. I will add only the version that uses `data.table` or `base` R here. I will reference your answer and add a comment about the benchmark though.

Answer (score 1):

Using a lookup table:

```
LUT <- data.table(sex = c("Male", "Female", ""), to=c("M", "F", NA), key = "sex")
```

You could

```
dt[, sex := LUT[.SD, to]]
```

Or for extra speed

```
library(collapse)
dt[, sex := join(.SD, LUT, on = key(.SD), how = "left", verbose = FALSE)$to]
```